# How can I bind expression which uses itself?

Tags: clojure

Cause I have a `lazy-seq` to calculate fibonacci sequence.

```
(def fibonacci
  (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fibonacci (rest fibonacci))))
=> #'user/fibonacci
(take 10 fibonacci)
=> (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

But when I try to put `fibonacci` into `let`

```
(let [fibonacci
  (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fibonacci (rest fibonacci)))]
  (take 10 fibonacci))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: fibonacci in this context, compiling:...
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike with `def`, the binding of `x` to `f` made by `(let [x f] ...)` is not visible inside `f`. More precisely, binding to `x` is done after evaluating `f`. In order to have recursive definitions, you need to use `letfn`, which is for defining functions. Consequently, you can no longer treat `fibonacci` as a `LazySeq`, but you can define it as a function returning a `LazySeq`:

```
(letfn [(fibonacci [] 
          (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + (fibonacci) (rest (fibonacci)))))]
  (take 10 (fibonacci)))
```

Comment: This is "correct", but **SUPER** inefficient. It's exactly the example used to show how not to do fibonacci, because it takes O(2^n) time to find the nth fibonacci number, instead of just O(n). Try `(nth (fibonacci) 50)`, which by a back-of-the-envelope calculation should take a couple months to complete.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks. This is a fair warning w.r.t. the proper way to compute fibonacci. Note however that the focus here not really about this sequence in particular but about recursive bindings. The linked question and its answers are perfectly relevant, of course.

Comment: But this isn't a recursive binding of a value at all, which is what was being asked for. It's a recursive binding of a function, which (presumably) speedcell4 already knew how to do.

Comment: I did not claim this to be a recursive binding of a *value* (and I'd be happy to see an example of such a binding in Clojure). OP basically asks "here it works with `def`, but not with `let`, why?".

Comment: There are at least two examples of that in the question this has been marked as a duplicate of: my second answer, and ord's macro on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you want this construction to work in `let`, then you won't be able to write such type of code:

```
(defn override-variables [x]
  (let [x (do-some-stuff-with x)]
    (do-stuff x))
```

And this situation is much more frequent that defining lazy sequences in terms of variables in locals.

But you can call anonymous function in it's body if you give the name to it  with `(fn fib-func [args] ...)` and construct lazy-seq in terms of functions, not variables.

```
(let [fib ((fn rfib [a b] 
             (lazy-seq (cons a (rfib b (+ a b)))))
           0 1)]
  (take 10 fib))
```